# fetching files in a loop as an input to a script

Tags: shell, loops

I have a bunch of files and a script which I run on them. That script takes 2 files as an input and all files are in this format: a.txt1 a.txt2

Now the script I use is like this: foo.sh a.txt1 a.txt2

I have to run this script run on 250 pairs (eg. a1.txt1 a1.txt2 to a250.txt1 a250.txt2)
I am doing this manually by entering file names. I was wondering is there any way to automate this process. All these pairs are in same folder, is there any way to loop the process on all pairs?

I hope I made it clear.

Thank you.

To be specific, these are some sample file names:

- T39_C.txt2
- T39_D.txt1
- T39_D.txt2
- T40_A.txt1
- T40_A.txt2
- T40_B.txt1
- T40_B.txt2
- T40_C.txt1
- T40_C.txt2
- T40_D.txt1
- T40_D.txt2
- unmatched.txt1
- unmatched.txt2
- WT11_A.txt1
- WT11_A.txt2
- WT11_B.txt1
- WT11_B.txt2
- WT11_C.txt1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all files are in pairs (ie, `<something>.txt1` and `<something>.txt2` then you can do something line this:

```
1. #!/bin/bash
2.
3. for txt1 in *.txt1; do
4.    txt2="${txt1%1}2"
5.    # work on $txt1 and $txt2
6. done
```

In line 3, we use a shell glob to grab all files ending with `.txt1`. Line 4, we use a substitution to remove the final `1` and replace it with a `2`. And the real work is done in line 5.

Comment: hi,
Thank you for the reply. I have edited my post. Please suggest me based on the file names. I am new to linux.. I hope you people dont mind if its too simple..

Comment: This is becoming either too generic or too specific, don't you have a generic pattern which your files must obey in order to be processed at all?

Comment: No sir, but all pairs are end with .txt1 and .txt2

Comment: OK, so this means if for a file <something>.txt1, there is no <something>.txt2 then you don't do anything, right?

Comment: yes sir. But all files are paired so I dont think there will be any such problem.

Comment: See edited answer, although it is unclear what you want to do with each file pair. The delegated work may be another shell script, as well.

Comment: ty ty ty ty very much ! I did some minor modifications but worked like a charm :) :)

Comment: Line 4, you probably mean `${txt1%1}2` instead of `$(txt1%1)2` (the latter would try to run the command `txt1%1` which probably doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

*#FOR EACH FILE IN THE CURRENT DIRECTORY EXCEPT FOR THE FILES WITH .txt2**
 for i in `ls | sort | grep -v .txt2`
      do

```
       *#THE FIRST .txt1 file is $i*
       first="$i"

       *#THE SECOND IS THE SAME EXCEPT WITH .txt2 SO WE REPLACE THE STRING*
       second=`echo "$i" | sed 's/.txt1/.txt2/g'`

        #WE MAKE THE ASSUMPTION FOO.SH WILL ERROR OUT IF NOT PASSED TWO PARAMETERS
        if !(bash foo.sh $first $second); then
        {
           echo "Problem running against $first $second"
         }
           else
        {
         echo "Ran against $first $second"
        }
        fi
done
```